# Masonry layout with only PHP and CSS?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I have a testimonial blog page using WordPress, but I want the posts to be displayed like pinterest. I know how to do this with HTML and CSS, but is there a way to achieve this without using a JavaScript library?

Here is a picture of the design I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

This is a standard blog page using the posts, no custom post types involved.

My current PHP code:

```
<div class="container blog-page-container">
 <?php if (have_posts()) {
    $count = 0;
    echo '<div class="col-md-4">';
    while( have_posts() ) : the_post();
        if($count == 3) {
            $count % 3;
            echo '</div><div class="col-md-4">';
        };
        ?>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="testimonial-background">
                <div class="testimonial-text">
            <span>
                <i class="fas fa-quote-left fa-3x"></i>
                <p><?php echo the_content(); ?></p>
                <p><strong><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></strong></p>
            </span>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php $count++;
    endwhile;
    echo '</div>';
}; ?>
</div>
```

But this is how I want the code to be output: https://jsfiddle.net/wrpuu7wh/

```js
$('.testimonial-text:odd').addClass("testimonial-text-opposite");
```

```css
.col-md-12 {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}

.col-md-4 {
  width: 33.33333333%;
  float: left;
}

.testimonial-background {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.testimonial-text {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #4E0B1C;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  padding-right: 40px;
}

.testimonial-text-opposite {
  color: #4E0B1C;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #4E0B1C;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.10/js/all.js"></script>

<div class="container blog-page-container">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="testimonial-background">
        <div class="testimonial-text">
          <span>
                    <i class="fas fa-quote-left fa-3x"></i>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscingelit. </p>
                    <p><strong>Post 1</strong></p>
                </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="testimonial-background">
        <div class="testimonial-text">
          <span>
                    <i class="fas fa-quote-left fa-3x"></i>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscingelit. Nam velit dolor,     tincidunt cursus nisl eget, auctor vehicula sem. Aliquam eget nunclacinia, pulvinar erat eget, finibus mauris.</p>
                    <p><strong>Post 4</strong></p>
                </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="testimonial-background">
        <div class="testimonial-text">
          <span>
                    <i class="fas fa-quote-left fa-3x"></i>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscingelit. Nam velit dolor,     tincidunt cursus nisl eget, auctor vehicula sem. Aliquam eget nunclacinia, pulvinar erat eget, finibus mauris.</p>
                    <p><strong>Post 7</strong></p>
                </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="testimonial-background">
        <div class="testimonial-text">
          <span>
                    <i class="fas fa-quote-left fa-3x"></i>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscingelit. Nam velit dolor,     tincidunt cursus nisl eget, auctor vehicula sem. Aliquam eget nunclacinia, pulvinar erat eget, finibus mauris.
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscingelit. Nam velit dolor,     tincidunt cursus nisl eget, auctor vehicula sem. Aliquam eget nunclacinia, pulvinar erat eget, finibus mauris.</p>
                    <p><strong>Post 2</strong></p>
                </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="testimonial-background">
        <div class="testimonial-text">
          <span>
                    <i class="fas fa-quote-left fa-3x"></i>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscingelit. Nam velit dolor,     tincidunt cursus nisl eget, auctor vehicula sem. Aliquam eget nunclacinia, pulvinar erat eget, finibus mauris.</p>
                    <p><strong>Post 5</strong></p>
                </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="testimonial-background">
        <div class="testimonial-text">
          <span>
                    <i class="fas fa-quote-left fa-3x"></i>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscingelit. Nam velit dolor..</p>
                    <p><strong>Post 8</strong></p>
                </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="testimonial-background">
        <div class="testimonial-text">
          <span>
                    <i class="fas fa-quote-left fa-3x"></i>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscingelit. Nam velit dolor,     tincidunt cursus nisl eget, auctor vehicula sem. Aliquam eget nunclacinia, pulvinar erat eget, finibus mauris.
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscingelit. Nam velit dolor,     tincidunt cursus nisl eget, auctor vehicula sem. Aliquam eget nunclacinia, pulvinar erat eget, finibus mauris.</p>
                    <p><strong>Post 3</strong></p>
                </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="testimonial-background">
        <div class="testimonial-text">
          <span>
                    <i class="fas fa-quote-left fa-3x"></i>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscingelit. Nam velit dolor,     tincidunt cursus nisl eget, auctor vehicula sem. Aliquam eget nunclacinia, pulvinar erat eget, finibus mauris.</p>
                    <p><strong>Post 6</strong></p>
                </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="testimonial-background">
        <div class="testimonial-text">
          <span>
                    <i class="fas fa-quote-left fa-3x"></i>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscingelit. Nam velit dolor,     tincidunt cursus nisl eget, auctor vehicula sem. Aliquam eget nunclacinia, pulvinar erat eget, finibus mauris.</p>
                    <p><strong>Post 9</strong></p>
                </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wrpuu7wh/

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE: Using my PHP code I am now getting 2 columns but the posts are being displayed as:

```
1    4
2    5
3    6
     7
     8
```

My desired output:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

Comment: Maybe check [this post](https://codeburst.io/how-to-pure-css-masonry-layouts-a8ede07ba31a) and [this fiddle](https://codepen.io/jh3y/pen/mPgyqw).

Comment: My fiddle shows the layout I'm aiming for, but I'm trying to achieve this design by only using PHP, if the page was hardcoded it would be easily achievable.

Comment: You are doing opposite/wrong, you should wrap 3 x `<div class="col-md-12">` inside `<div class="col-md-4">`. What you also need is to check counter (how it starts, when you increment) and use `$count % 3`

Comment: I've updated my code and it's close! Currently, I have 2 columns but 3 posts are appearing in the first column and the rest in the second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to divide your posts in columns, than to output them. You can do it this way for example:

```html
/* Total published posts should be returned this way: */
$count_posts = wp_count_posts()->publish;
$count_rows = round($count_posts/3);
$post_columns = array(
    array(),
    array(),
    array()
);
?>
<div class="container blog-page-container">
    <?php if (have_posts()) {
    $count = 0;
    while( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    $post_column_number = $count;
    $post_columns[$count%3][] = array(
        'title' => get_the_title(),
        'content' => the_content()
    );
    $count++;
    endwhile;
    foreach( $post_columns as $pc ) {
        echo '<div class="col-md-4">';
        foreach( $pc as $pt ) {
            echo "
                <div class='col-md-12'>
                    <div class='testimonial-background'>
                        <div class='testimonial-text'>
                            <span>
                                <i class='fas fa-quote-left fa-3x'>
                                </i>
                                <p>{$pt['content']}</p>
                                <p>
                                    <strong>{$pt['title']}</strong>
                                </p>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            ";
        };
        echo '</div>';
    };
};?>
```

Hope you get the idea.

Complete test code below:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.10/js/all.js" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<?php
/* COMING FROM WORDPRESS: */
$posts = array(
    array(
        'title' => 'Title 1',
        'content' => 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscingelit.'
    ),
    array(
        'title' => 'Title 2',
        'content' => 'Nam velit dolor, tincidunt cursus nisl eget, auctor vehicula sem. Aliquam eget '
    ),
    array(
        'title' => 'Title 3',
        'content' => 'Nam velit dolor, tincidunt cursus nisl eget, auctor vehicula sem. Aliquam eget nunclacinia, pulvinar erat eget, finibus mauris. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscingelit. Nam velit dolor, tincidunt cursus nisl eget, auctor vehicula sem. Aliquam eget nunclacinia, pulvinar erat eget, finibus mauris'
    ),
    array(
        'title' => 'Title 4',
        'content' => 'Nam velit dolor, tincidunt cursus nisl eget, auctor vehicula sem. Aliquam eget '
    ),
    array(
        'title' => 'Title 5',
        'content' => 'Aliquam eget nunclacinia, pulvinar erat eget, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscingelit.'
    ),
    array(
        'title' => 'Title 6',
        'content' => 'Nam velit dolor, tincidunt cursus nisl eget, auctor vehicula sem. Aliquam eget '
    ),
    array(
        'title' => 'Title 3',
        'content' => 'Nam velit dolor, tin amet, consectetur adipcidunt cursus nisl eget, auctor vehicula sem. Aliquam eget nunclacinia, pulvinar erat eget, finibus mauris. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscingelit. Nam velit dolor, tincidunt cursus nisl eget, auctor vehicula sem. Aliquam eget nunclacinia, pulvinar erat eget, finibus mauris'
    ),
);
function have_posts() {
    global $posts;
    return count($posts);
}
function the_post() {
    global $posts, $post;
    $post = array_shift( $posts );
}
function the_content() {
    global $post;
    return $post['content'];
}
function get_the_title() {
    global $post;
    return $post['title'];
}
/* YOUR CODE BELOW */
/* Total published posts should be returned this way:
$count_posts = wp_count_posts()->publish;
*/
$count_posts = count( $posts );
$count_rows = round($count_posts/3);
$post_columns = array(
    array(),
    array(),
    array()
);
?>
<div class="container blog-page-container">
    <?php if (have_posts()) {
    $count = 0;
    while( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    $post_column_number = $count;
    $post_columns[$count%3][] = array(
        'title' => get_the_title(),
        'content' => the_content()
    );
    $count++;
    endwhile;
    foreach( $post_columns as $pc ) {
        echo '<div class="col-md-4">';
        foreach( $pc as $pt ) {
            echo "
                <div class='col-md-12'>
                    <div class='testimonial-background'>
                        <div class='testimonial-text'>
                            <span>
                                <i class='fas fa-quote-left fa-3x'>
                                </i>
                                <p>{$pt['content']}</p>
                                <p>
                                    <strong>{$pt['title']}</strong>
                                </p>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            ";
        };
        echo '</div>';
    };
};?>
</div>
<style>
    .col-md-12 {
        width: 100%;
        float: left;
    }
    .col-md-4 {
        width: 33.33333333%;
        float: left;
    }
    .testimonial-background {
        margin-top: 0;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        padding-left: 20px;
    }
    .testimonial-text {
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #4E0B1C;
        padding-top: 20px;
        padding-left: 20px;
        padding-bottom: 20px;
        padding-right: 40px;
    }
    .testimonial-text-opposite {
        color: #4E0B1C;
        background-color: #fff;
        border: 1px solid #4E0B1C;
    }
</style>
<script>
    $('.testimonial-text:odd').addClass("testimonial-text-opposite");
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! The code was outputting the content on top of the columns but I changed 'the_content' to 'get_the_content' and that fixed the problem.